# What is the ideal way of defining folder structure for enterprise level angular2 application?

Tags: angular

As per the Angular docs, all application logic will be inside the `app` folder and `app.module.ts` will act as a root module for entire application.

https://angular.io/guide/file-structure

But I would like to know, Is there any other preferable way of defining folder structure for enterprise level angular application?

Answer (score 1):

This course might help you.

[Angular architecture best practices](https://app.pluralsight.com/library/courses/angular-architecture-best-practices/table-of-contents)

Comment: Looks like a good resource. Please consider recapping highlights in your answer: the link might change, or the course get taken off-line, which'll make this thread not useful to future visitors.